Which input features do I need to drop after examining variance inflation factor (VIF)?
For example, I got the following VIF factor result (weekday_ is one-hot encoding):
    VIF Factor                  features
0     0.000000                 Intercept
...
9    51.136294             utc_timestamp
10   19.603974            weekday_Friday
11   10.239841          weekday_Saturday
12    4.681547            weekday_Sunday
13   25.088306          weekday_Thursday
14    3.623731           weekday_Tuesday
15   35.704364         weekday_Wednesday
16    3.957419           hour_of_day_cos
17   13.686298           hour_of_day_sin
18   64.972848                    temp_c
19    7.335685               pressure_mb
20   23.209039                  humidity
21    1.526779                   rain_mm

Given the data (or any arbitrary data), how can I determine which input features need to be dropped? My understanding is that, VIF factor only tells about an individual feature. It does not tell that which features are highly correlated.
In this situation, how do I determine which features need to be dropped?

Drop a feature with the highest VIF factor value first
Drop a feature which seems less explanable the phenomenon physically or semnatically
Other approach

